# Why getting an error when using JDBC in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC and Java but I am facing with a few problems ...

I add in my pom.xml file this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my java code :

```
public static void initDriver(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void connectBDD(){
    initDriver();

    String url = new String("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+BDDPort+"/"+BDDName);
    String utilisateur = BDDUser;
    String motDePasse = BDDPassword;
    Connection connexion = null;
    try {
        connexion = DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );    

        Statement statement = connexion.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery( "SHOW TABLES;" );

        System.out.println(resultat.toString());

        resultat.close();           

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {stack trace I am getting : 


        if ( connexion != null ){
            try {
                connexion.close();
            } catch ( SQLException ignore ) {
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

When executing this code, here is what I can see from the println request : com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@2e3fc542

I think it is a null pointer exception hidden beside it but I don't know how to solve it...

If anyone could help me... Thank you !

**UPDATE**

Here is another code I tried and its stacktrace :

```
    ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT id FROM COURRIER;" );

    while ( resultat.next() ) {
        Integer password = resultat.getInt("id");

        System.out.println(password);
    }
    resultat.close();
```

Stack trace :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'myDB.COURRIER' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1994)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1429)
    at utils.BDDInitializer.connectBDD(BDDInitializer.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
```

Comment: Please post the _entire_ stacktrace. `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@2e3fc542` seems to be the result of this statement: `System.out.println(resultat.toString());`, so what's missing is the stacktrace. Besides that, if you get a result set then the query itself should work, otherwise you'd not reach that print statement.

Comment: Works as expected. Perhaps you have the wrong expectations for `System.out.println(resultat.toString());` (It's not an `NPE`)

Comment: That is not how you use a `ResultSet`.

Comment: if you reach System.out.println then there's no exception. What you see is the result of the toString method of the resultset implementation of the jdbc driver you are using. It's all ok

Comment: don't you think the stack trace is self explanatory... jdbc is unable to find the table 'COURRIER' or you are making it connect to the wrong machine if it indeed exists

Comment: My bad : it was not "COURRIER" but "courrier". Sorry for that !

Comment: @LauraG is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes it is :) thank you for your interest

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are printing the ResultSet itself.

The below shows how you use the ResultSet:

```
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection( url, utilisateur, motDePasse );    

    Statement statement = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT EMP_NAME from Employees" );

    while(rs.next()){
         String str = rs.getString("EMP_NAME");//here rs will be having multiple methods for multiple data types, EMP_NAME is the column name
         System.out.println(str);
    }

    rs.close();
```

This will help

Comment: I think that adding an explicative reference like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html your answer could be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in fact running and executing the query without problems. The fact that you get something like `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@2e3fc542` printed is because you are calling `toString()` on the `ResultSet` returned by the query, and the `ResultSet` does not have an overridden `toString()` method.

To print the data in the `ResultSet` in a nice way, you need to iterate over it and print the fields in each row:

```
while (resultat.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultat.getString(1));
}
```

Instead of what you have now:

```
System.out.println(resultat.toString());
```